# Best practice for volume aliases in config files

Tags: craft3, config, volumes

I'm wondering about using a `config/volumes.php` file to specify volume aliases (instead of putting them in `config/general.php`). There's a comment in a previous codebase mentioning https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#overriding-volume-settings but that seems to have been removed and now we can't find documentation about creating additional config files.

I see this somewhat related post and that @robin-schambach posted with a suggestion to put volume aliases alongside of other ones in `config/general.php`.

[Craft 3: how can I set dynamic Base URL in sites setting?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/craft-3-how-can-i-set-dynamic-base-url-in-sites-setting/23714)

So, is it best practice to create a `config/volumes.php` just for volume aliases or should they be kept in `config/general.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the power of commit history.

[@brandon-kelly](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/9/brandon-kelly) removed the volumes config section from the v3 docs [back in February](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/59649678a6d486fc2e7d947e25ab51a3d09f658f#diff-170a3f2c0a87c4f6c25b4d944865f1c8), mentioning

> Environment variables solve the same problem better.

So it seems that the best practice is to create volume aliases in `config/general.php`.